# Search and Populate on Angular2

Tags: angular

I have pulled a set of data in a div from firebase in my angular2 application. The data includes the first names, date of birth and last names. 
I have created a SEARCH input box. Now I want to populate the div with the data matching that search box only, with the name. I tried to use  [Search Filter Pipe](https://hassantariqblog.wordpress.com/2017/03/16/angular2-creating-custom-search-filter-pipe-for-ngfor-directive/) , but could not succeed. Could anyone help?
Below is my code:

```
member.service.ts:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, 
              AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 
    'angularfire2/database-deprecated';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { Member } from '../models/Member';


@Injectable()
 export class MemberService{
 membersCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Member>;
 members: Observable<Member[]>;
 memberDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<Member>;

constructor(
 public afs: AngularFirestore,
 public afd: AngularFireDatabase) { 


 this.members = this.afs.collection('members').snapshotChanges().map(changes 
                  =>{ return changes.map(a => {
    const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Member;
    data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
    return data;
        });
    });
  }

 getMembers(){
   return this.members;
   }
 }


 member.ts
 export interface Member{
        id?: string;
        name?: string;
        birthdate?: string;
        lastname?: string;
      }

  members.component.ts
  import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
  import { MemberService } from '../../services/member.service';
  import { Member } from '../../models/Member';

   @Component({
    selector: 'app-members',
    templateUrl: './members.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./members.component.css']
    })
  export class MembersComponent implements OnInit{
     members: Member[];

 constructor(private memberService: MemberService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.memberService.getMembers().subscribe(members => {
//  console.log(members);
  this.members = members;
});
}
}


 members.component.html
 <input #txtMember placeholder="Search members..."/>
 <div *ngIf="members?.length > 0;else noMembers">
  <ul *ngFor="let member of members" class="collection">
    <li class="collection-item"><strong>{{member.name:}}</strong> 
                             {{member.birthdate}}{{member.lastname}}></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please add the code to your question

Comment: I have added the codes.

Comment: @Pikey update your html file as i have suggested in my answer below and add the search pipe to your project. check if that works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ng model on your search input box and pass this to filter your data

html file is as follows .

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="input"/>
<table>
  <tr>
  <th>First Name</th>
  <th>Last Name</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of data | searchPipe: input">
    <td>{{item.firstName}}</td>
    <td>{{item.lastName}}</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

search pipe is as follows.

```
 transform (data, str: string): any {
    if (str === undefined || str == null || str == '')
      return data;

    return data.filter(function (obj) {
      return Object.keys(obj).some(function (key) {
        return obj[key].toString().toLowerCase().includes(str.toLowerCase());
      });
    });
  }
```

if the search input box is empty it will return the same data. When you type in the search box it will pass the input in search box to the search pipe, filter the data and return the filtered data.

you can check the working example here.

[working example](https://angular-q5w4vw.stackblitz.io)

Comment: It worked. I was doing in the wrong way. #Newbie. Thanks.